# Calculating weighted hog features

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am getting hog features of a human body in a image which resulted after grabcut. However I have to get the weighted hog features i.e. give special weight to face and arms then rest of the body. So I have detected the face and arms region however I am uncertain how to get the weighted combination of the hog features.

Image size - (307,220)

Number of Hog Features - 1976

Settings - `fd, hog_image = hog(im, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=True);`

I am using skimage in python.

Please give any pointers as I am not able to think of any starting point to do so.

Thanks

Comment: How are you using HoG features? Method of weighting them depends on your use case. Also if you are using them as data in SVM, then you don't need to weight them, because SVM will find its own weights

Comment: I am going to create a manifold of the hog features not svm...Basically I want to take more of arm motion and head movement across the image while reducing their dimensions